# Python Function: Loop Through a "Key:Value" Dictionary And Append The Last "Value" Word To an Output String Based on the Dictionary's Key

Tags: python, function, loops, dictionary, number-sequence

Let's say I have the following dictionary:

```
sorted_dict = {1: 'You', 2: 'teeth', 3: 'are', 4: 'mood', 5: 'test', 6: 'helpful'}
```

Each word is associated with a number and I want to arrange the words into a pyramid like the example below:

```
1
2 3
4 5 6
```

The trick here is I only want the words corresponding to the numbers at the end of each line (1, 3, 6).  All other words are discarded.  So:

```
1: You
3: are
6: helpful
```

In the end I want to return a string associated with numbers 1, 3, 6.  In my example the desired output would be:

```
"You are helpful"
```

I've started trying to write the function for this (see below).  But I don't know how to get the pyramid pattern 1, 3, 6 in my loop to get the right words out.  Please note this is a small example but I want my function (with this pyramid pattern) to run on a dictionary that potentially has thousands of words.

```
def test(input_list):
    output_str = ""
    
    i = 1
    
    for key, value in sorted_dict.items():
        
        print(key, value)
        
        # i += ? 
        # if statement here to only append string to output_str if it equals the right i number 
        output_str += ' ' + value
        
    
    return output_str
```

My current function above returns: `' You teeth are mood test helpful'` which is incorrect

How do I fix this?

Comment: The pattern is `1`, `1+2`, `1+2+3`, ...

Comment: I mathematically understand the pattern ... but code wise how do I capture it using an i counting iterator?

Comment: You can use the formula `i * (i+1) / 2` to get the desired key for the ith word. Also, if you're just using natural numbers as the key, why not just use a list?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't need to loop through the dictionary. Generate the keys using simple arithmetic, the sequence is `1`, `1+2`, `1+2+3`, and so on. Stop when the key isn't found in the dictionary.

```
key = 1
increment = 2
output_list = []

while key in sorted_dict:
    output_list.append(sorted_dict[key])
    key += increment
    increment += 1

output_str = " ".join(output_list)
```

Comment: Thank you for the response.  Your code tested against my dictionary produces "You teeth mood" which is not what I am looking for.  

I cannot generate my own keys.  The key value pairs dictionary is given to me and I must use it as is.

Comment: I think it should work now, I had the wrong starting increment.

Comment: it worked!  what an elegant solution too ... thank you!